# Struts DispatchAction in version 1.2.9

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I'm working on a legacy system and have a question about `DispatchAction` class. The project I'm working on using Struts version `1.2.9`. I tried to upgrade it to version `2.0.0` but I got a problem with all my action classes. It says `DispatchAction cannot be resolved to a type`. Is this class removed from version 2? What can I use instead of it for a smooth transition?

Comment: You should update to the latest vertsion

Answer (score 2):

There is essentially zero relationship between Struts 1 and Struts 2.

If you want to migrate to Struts 2 you should learn about Struts 2, and use a recent version (Struts 2.0.0 is quite old now). There are a few (somewhat outdated) S1 -> S2 migration guides, e.g., https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Migration+Guide

But you'll want to take a step back and at least figure out what you're talking about, because you seem to have no idea what S2 is. Not criticizing, just warning.